# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0 in swing

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtable

I have inserted a `JTable` in mu `JFrame` and trying to add rows from a result set, but it is showing

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
```

the code is given below:

```
String billSelect_Sql = "select bill.bill_id, transaction.date, bill.product_desc, bill.quantity, bill.rate, transaction.debt, transaction.crdt, transaction.closing_balance from bill, transaction where bill.user_id = transaction.user_id and bill.user_id = '"+uid+"';";
            Statement ST2=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet RS2 = ST2.executeQuery(billSelect_Sql)

            int rowCount = 0;
            while(RS2.next()){

               billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getString("bill_id"), rowCount, 1);
               billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getString("date"), rowCount, 2);
               billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getString("product_desc"), rowCount, 3);
               billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getInt("quantity"), rowCount, 4);
               billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getDouble("rate"), rowCount, 5);
               billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getDouble("debt"), rowCount, 6);
               billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getDouble("crdt"), rowCount, 7);
               billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getDouble("closing_balance"), rowCount, 8);
               rowCount = rowCount+1;
            }

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | NumberFormatException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

billing_tab is the Variable name of my jTable on jframe.
Showing error at the point:

```
billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getString("bill_id"), rowCount, 1);
```

Did I miss anything to add with this code ?

Comment: Add your code as well.

Comment: Can you show how you are instantiating the Array ?

Comment: I think your table has not enough rows. Simply increment number of rows in table on iterating.

Answer (score 1):

First of all variable names (ie. RS2, ST2) should NOT start with an upper case character. Then names should also be more descriptive. Most of your variable names are correct, but not all. Be consistent!!!

> trying to add rows from a result set

```
   billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getString("bill_id"), rowCount, 1);
   billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getString("date"), rowCount, 2);
   billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getString("product_desc"), rowCount, 3);
   billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getInt("quantity"), rowCount, 4);
   billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getDouble("rate"), rowCount, 5);
   billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getDouble("debt"), rowCount, 6);
   billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getDouble("crdt"), rowCount, 7);
   billing_tab.getModel().setValueAt(RS2.getDouble("closing_balance"), rowCount, 8);
   rowCount = rowCount+1;
```

Your model is empty so there is no data to change. Don't try to add data to the model using the setValueAt(...) method. That method is only for "changing" existing data in the model.

Instead you want to add a new row of data. So your code should be something like:

```
Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
row.addElement( RS2.getString("bill_id") );
row.addElement( RS2.getSTring("date") );
...
billing_tab.getModel().addRow( row );
```